# IDE with Spyder to works with both ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-pro, spyder, ide

I am searching for an IDE with Spyder that works with both ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap.

I did found a suggested answer [Using spyder as Python IDE with ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249770/using-spyder-as-python-ide-with-arcgis-pro), but would like to know if any more possibility exists.

Ideally, something like PyCharm does where you can easily switch between the two Python interpreters but if not then a separate IDE with Spyder for ArcMap (64-bit geoprocessing, Python 2.7).

Are there any IDEs or configurations that can do this?

Comment: What do you mean "an IDE with Spyder"? Only Spyder IDE comes with "Spyder". Is there specific Spyder functionality you are looking for in an alternative IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Most Python IDEs can do this. I personally use PyScripter. This link should help you.

https://community.esri.com/t5/python-documents/run-pyscripter-with-arcgis-pro-s-python-3-x-and-the-arcgis-api/tac-p/920531

Comment: That link is only about using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro, and using the ArcGIS Python API.  It is not about using ArcPy with ArcMap as asked for by the question.

Comment: @PolyGeo my understanding is he is asking for an IDE that works with both ArcGIS Pro, and ArcMap. Since the IDE is separate from ArcGIS Software, most IDEs are capable of this function. The poster of the question seems familiar with Spyder, however, many options are available. For instance, PyCharm is also an option, as the setting to recognize and work with specific Python installations resides within the IDE itself and is not reliant on the ArcGIS Software dialog options.

https://resources.esri.ca/getting-technical/configure-your-python-ide-to-work-with-arcmap-and-arcgis-pro-s-arcpy

Comment: @John Where in your answer does it address how to use Spyder with the Python 2.x ArcPy from ArcMap?  I think they had already found a Q&A related to using Spyder with the Python 3.x ArcPy from ArcGIS Pro.  If they're after software recommendations for something other than Spyder as their IDE then maybe we should just vote to close it as lacking focus.